# Use thymeleaf to populate form action

Tags: spring-mvc, thymeleaf

In Thymeleaf, I can output into a input's value using

```
<input th:value=${message} />
```

But I don't know how to output into the form action attribute.

Anyone ideas for the Thymeleaf HTML side?

Sample Java Spring-MVC controller code

```
@Controller
public class SampleController 
    @RequestMapping("/")
    public String home(Model model) {
        model.addAttribute("message", "Hello World!");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [`th:action`](http://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/articles/standardurlsyntax.html)

For example, if you wanted to use the `message` attribute as a parameter, you can do:

`th:action="@{/someUri/foo(message=${message})}"`